# Wechaty-padlocal Python ding-dong-bot example only responses when rerun

Tags: python, wechaty

I am trying Wechaty-Padlocal with ding-dong-bot example from https://github.com/wechaty/python-wechaty-getting-started/tree/master/examples:

```
"""doc"""
# pylint: disable=R0801
import asyncio
import logging
import os
from typing import Optional, Union

from wechaty_puppet import FileBox, ScanStatus  # type: ignore

from wechaty import Wechaty, Contact
from wechaty.user import Message, Room

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class MyBot(Wechaty):
    """
    listen wechaty event with inherited functions, which is more friendly for
    oop developer
    """
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    async def on_message(self, msg: Message):
        """
        listen for message event
        """
        from_contact = msg.talker()
        text = msg.text()
        room = msg.room()
        if text == '#ding':
            conversation: Union[
                Room, Contact] = from_contact if room is None else room
            await conversation.ready()
            await conversation.say('dong')
            file_box = FileBox.from_url(
                'https://ss3.bdstatic.com/70cFv8Sh_Q1YnxGkpoWK1HF6hhy/it/'
                'u=1116676390,2305043183&fm=26&gp=0.jpg',
                name='ding-dong.jpg')
            await conversation.say(file_box)

    async def on_login(self, contact: Contact):
        print(f'user: {contact} has login')

    async def on_scan(self, status: ScanStatus, qr_code: Optional[str] = None,
                      data: Optional[str] = None):
        contact = self.Contact.load(self.contact_id)
        print(f'user <{contact}> scan status: {status.name} , '
              f'qr_code: {qr_code}')


bot: Optional[MyBot] = None


async def main():
    """doc"""
    # pylint: disable=W0603
    global bot
    bot = MyBot()
    await bot.start()

os.environ['TOKEN'] = "puppet_padlocal_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
os.environ['WECHATY_PUPPET_SERVICE_ENDPOINT'] = "127.0.0.1:9001"

asyncio.run(main())
```

After sending "ding" to myself, I am not getting response of "dong" or image from the bot. Following is the output after sending "ding" to myself. However, rerun this program prompts the response of "dong" from myself.

```
2021-06-22 15:03:34,496 - Wechaty - INFO - on() listen event <scan> with <<function on_scan at 0x0000020F3CDD84C0>>
2021-06-22 15:03:34,496 - Wechaty - INFO - on() listen event <login> with <<function on_login at 0x0000020F3ECA7DC0>>
2021-06-22 15:03:34,496 - Wechaty - INFO - on() listen event <message> with <<function on_message at 0x0000020F3CDA88B0>>
2021-06-22 15:03:34,527 - Wechaty - INFO - init_puppet_event_bridge() <<wechaty_puppet_service.puppet.PuppetService object at 0x0000020F3F811CD0>>
2021-06-22 15:03:34,527 - Wechaty - INFO - initPuppetEventBridge() puppet.on(dong) (listenerCount:1) registering...
2021-06-22 15:03:34,527 - Wechaty - INFO - initPuppetEventBridge() puppet.on(error) (listenerCount:1) registering...
2021-06-22 15:03:34,527 - Wechaty - INFO - initPuppetEventBridge() puppet.on(heart-beat) (listenerCount:1) registering...
2021-06-22 15:03:34,527 - Wechaty - INFO - initPuppetEventBridge() puppet.on(ready) (listenerCount:1) registering...
2021-06-22 15:03:34,527 - Wechaty - INFO - receive <reset> event <%s>
2021-06-22 15:03:34,527 - Wechaty - INFO - initPuppetEventBridge() puppet.on(reset) (listenerCount:0) registering...
2021-06-22 15:03:34,527 - Wechaty - INFO - initPuppetEventBridge() puppet.on(friendship) (listenerCount:1) registering...
2021-06-22 15:03:34,527 - Wechaty - INFO - initPuppetEventBridge() puppet.on(login) (listenerCount:1) registering...
2021-06-22 15:03:34,527 - Wechaty - INFO - initPuppetEventBridge() puppet.on(logout) (listenerCount:1) registering...
2021-06-22 15:03:34,527 - Wechaty - INFO - initPuppetEventBridge() puppet.on(message) (listenerCount:1) registering...
2021-06-22 15:03:34,527 - Wechaty - INFO - initPuppetEventBridge() puppet.on(room-invite) (listenerCount:1) registering...
2021-06-22 15:03:34,527 - Wechaty - INFO - initPuppetEventBridge() puppet.on(room-join) (listenerCount:1) registering...
2021-06-22 15:03:34,527 - Wechaty - INFO - initPuppetEventBridge() puppet.on(room-leave) (listenerCount:1) registering...
2021-06-22 15:03:34,527 - Wechaty - INFO - initPuppetEventBridge() puppet.on(room-topic) (listenerCount:1) registering...
2021-06-22 15:03:34,527 - Wechaty - INFO - initPuppetEventBridge() puppet.on(scan) (listenerCount:1) registering...
2021-06-22 15:03:34,527 - Wechaty - INFO - starting puppet ...
2021-06-22 15:03:34,527 - HostiePuppet - INFO - init puppet
2021-06-22 15:03:34,527 - HostiePuppet - INFO - starting the puppet ...
2021-06-22 15:03:35,300 - HostiePuppet - INFO - puppet has started ...
2021-06-22 15:03:35,300 - HostiePuppet - INFO - listening the event from the puppet ...
2021-06-22 15:03:36,979 - wechaty.plugin - INFO - init the plugins ...
2021-06-22 15:03:36,980 - Wechaty - INFO - receive <login> event <EventLoginPayload(contact_id='wxid_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx')>
2021-06-22 15:03:36,984 - Contact - INFO - load contact <Contact <wxid_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx> <Mark>>
Contact <wxid_xxxxxxxxxxxxxx> <Mark>
2021-06-22 15:03:38,346 - Wechaty - INFO - receive <ready> event <EventReadyPayload(data='ready')>
2021-06-22 15:03:41,980 - Wechaty - INFO - receive <ready> event <EventReadyPayload(data='ready')>
```

This is what happened in my WeChat:
[image]

Any thoughts on this issue will be appreciated!